# Line break in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, line-breaks

I have textbox which should be used to send formatted text to remote application, and I should format it so it breaks on closest space to 30th character (spaces included) and that space on which line is broken, should be deleted, so it isn't taken to next row. And of course, it should do it to the end of the text (break, start counting again, break, and so on).
-Other Thing is that characters for formatting text should be excluded from counting.
I have solution, found here on SO, but it works for one row.

```
string sTemp = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 30);
sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @A ", "");
sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@A ", "");
sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @A", "");
sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@A", "");

sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @B ", "");
sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@B ", "");
sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @B", "");
sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@B", "");

int numberOfLeak = 30 - sTemp.Length;
var x = 30 + numberOfLeak;
if (textBox1.Text.Length > x)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(x, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Can someone please help to make this work for many lines, until the end of text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `<input type="text" />` (which is default markup generated for an `asp:textbox`) is supposed to have only one line of text.
You should use a textarea instead by setting the **TextMode** property to ***Multiline***:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="mytextarea"></asp:TextBox>
```

---

**Edit:**

I've come with this simple piece of code. It replaces the closest white space to the `range` position (so after or before this point):

```
int range = 10;
string txt = "helloooooo mister how do you do";

for (int i = range; i < txt.Length - 1; i = i + range + 2)
{
    int closestPosition = txt.IndexOf(" ", i) > txt.LastIndexOf(" ", i)
                              ? txt.IndexOf(" ", i)
                              : txt.LastIndexOf(" ", i);

    txt = txt.Remove(closestPosition, 1).Insert(closestPosition, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

It returns me the following piece of string:

```
"helloooooo\r\nmister how\r\ndo you do"
```

Comment: I did that. But I need specific line break as I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to work perfect!
Do you have idea how to put this together with code in my question, so it removes from counting strings like "%A"?

Comment: Can you post an example of the text so i get the real picture ?

Answer (score 0):

If that solution works for one row, just put it into a method and call it in a loop for each line. e.g.

```
    // put the lines in an array
    string[] result = textBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string line in result)
    {
        output.AppendLine(WorkingSolutionForOneLine(line));
    }

    string finalResult = output.ToString();
```

with the WorkingSolutionForOneLine method being the working method that you posted in your question:

```
string WorkingSolutionForOneLine(string line)
{
    string sTemp = line.Substring(0, 30);
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @A ", "");
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@A ", "");
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @A", "");
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@A", "");

    sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @B ", "");
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@B ", "");
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace(" @B", "");
    sTemp = sTemp.Replace("@B", "");

    int numberOfLeak = 30 - sTemp.Length;
    var x = 30 + numberOfLeak;
    if (line.Length > x)
    {
        line = line.Insert(x, Environment.NewLine);
    }
    return line;
}
```